# Jenkins: Windows slave, linux master, how to configure (ant) build tools properly?

Tags: linux, windows, ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins 1.5XX master node running on centos/linux that builds java stuff with maven and ant. It works perfectly for a long time.

Now I want to add a Windows slave to build C++ windows programs and stuff. They were previously built on a separate jenkins server but it died and I lost everything.

I created a windows VM and managed to setup a slave node on the vm with the [doc provided in the jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines). The node/jenkins windows service works.

I created a Job to be runned on the windows slave and tied it to the slave via the config. It works since I see `Building remotely on bld2-windows in workspace C:\Software\Jenkins\workspace\mgmt`.

My Ant installations are defined in the global properties and are working and existing on the linux node.

In the windows node config I defined "Tool Locations" for the Ant installation and targeted a valid Ant install on the windows xp server: "Home = C:\Software\Liberty\ant"

Although, it crashes after the checkout with the error msg: `FATAL: Cannot find executable from the chosen Ant installation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the path and `ANT_HOME` were not properly configured on the windows node. in order to fix this, in windows, go to `"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables"` and define `ANT_HOME`.

To test ant install on windows, I suggest you open a cmd prompt and type `ant.bat` if it opens ant, you are good.

On the jenkins node setup, no need to define any tools location or override anything. Just use ant default in the job config.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the setup needs to be completed at the node config in order to properly pick up ant, java etc. With these settings properly configured, my builds run fine on the slave.

```
host:8080/computer/[NODENAME]/configure
```

Node properties:

- List of key-value pairs

  ```
  name: ANT_HOME
  value: [Path to ant root]
  name: JAVA_HOME
  value: [Path to java (jdk) root]
  name:PATH
  value:%PATH%;[Path to ant root]\bin
  ```
- Tool Locations

  ```
  Name:(Ant) 1.9.4
  Home:[Path to ant root]
  Name:(JDK) 1.7.0_25
  Home:[Path to java (jdk) root]
  ```

Comment: Not sure but I think I gave it a try back then. I'll try it back and confirm if it works for me to set the win PATH on the linux master.